# JMeter 403 Error - CSRF Token

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, load-testing

I am load testing a CSRF protected website and have successfully extracted the csrf token and authorized the login, however when loading a pages with many different graphs, all the graphs seem to fail. The transaction returned from JMeter has a large JSON response for the body data and an X-CSRF-TOKEN in the header.

Everything works fine when manually going through the webpage, only on JMeter is it failing.

I extract the CSRF cert at the login page, and send it to the login transaction parameters which works.

[image: Extractor]

[image: Login Parameters]

[image: Example Captured Token]

Here is one of the failed transactions (all others are the same) - It is a large JSON POST request

[image: Failed Transaction Body Data]

[image: Failed Transaction Header Request]

And this is the response from the failed transaction. As you can see the X-CSRF-TOKEN is entirely different from the one I passed in the header and says it's forbidden because of the CSRF. I also tried going through again to see if I could find a CSRF token that looks similar to the one in the response header, but I cannot.

[image: Failed Transaction Response Header]

[image: Failed Transaction Response Body]

So my question would be, why does this fail but the login passes with the same CSRF token? Is there an extra token generated somewhere? I have not been able to find any token generated that looks similar to the one in the header.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck on this for some time now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you need to extract the token not only from Login Page, but also from **each subsequent page**

As per [Synchronizer Token Pattern](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#synchronizer-token-pattern) chapter:

> CSRF tokens should be generated on the server-side. They can be generated once per user session **or for each request.** Per-request tokens are more secure than per-session tokens as the time range for an attacker to exploit the stolen tokens is minimal.

So try moving your `uaa_cert` extractor one level up so it will be applied to all [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers instead of only one (thanks to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide)) and it should resolve your issue. If it doesn't - double check the way you're passing the token